# Intuitively understanding a probability-problem

Tags: probability-theory

Two teams take part at a KO-tournament with n rounds. Assuming, that the teams
 win all their games until they are paired together, what is the probability
 that they both meet in the final ?

I figured out that the solution is

$P_n=\prod_{j=2}^n (1-\frac{1}{2^j-1})=\frac{2^{n-1}}{2^n-1}$

So, $\lim_{n->\infty} P_n = \frac{1}{2}$

I tried to understand the result intuitively because I would have expected a much
 lower probability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on the nice approach given by @Wonder:

The tournament defines a tree with $2^n$ leaves. One of the teams starts at one of those leaves. The other team may start at one of the $2^{n-1} - 1$ leaves in the same "half" of the tree as the first team, or one of the  $2^{n-1}$ leaves in the other "half" of the tree.

That is, of the $2^n - 1$ possible starting points for the second team (once you know
the starting point of the first team), $2^{n-1}$ prevent the teams from meeting until
the final match.
This corresponds to the exact probability you computed.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the binary tree defined by the tournament. If the teams are on different 'halves' of the tree at the start, then and only then will they meet in the final. Suppose you fix the side of one of the teams. You should be able to see that probability of choosing the other one from the same half is roughly half, especially as n tends to infinity.